# I don't understand how postgres is installed (OSX)

Tags: macos, postgresql, installation

Im still having issues installing postgres and really do not understand all that is going on.
( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472988/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory/12474965#comment16833278_12474965 )

I've been using the homebrew installer and then some people have recommended Heroku's Postgres.app install. Regardless I have no idea how to debug why it does not install as I do not understand what it's trying to do.

I mainly use Postgres for my rails app.

I'll accept the answer that best explains how postgres is installed and the different approaches in a way that can help me to better debug issues myself.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Must be Mac OS X given the mention of Postgres.app

Comment: Oh sorry, yes OSX Mountain Lion